# What should be included in a support letter?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I would like to know is there any format or things have to be aware when writing a support letter?

The letter is to support the application of a student to an award.

Comment: In what capacity do you know the student?  As an advisor, instructor, something else?

Answer (score 1):

A great letter of support for a student will include the standard elements of a recommendation.

- Your relation to the student (lecturer, lab supervisor, academic mentor, etc.)
- The student's significant contributions to the school, the community, and the specific program.
- The student's academic excellence
- Other important factors. (Why are you being asked for this letter of support? What do you know about this student that supports their suitability for this award?)

In all of these, be specific. Don't just say "X is an excellent student". Say "X is an excellent student, as evidenced by their insightful participation in class, their strong paper (won an award at [student conference in field]), and their continued dedication to learning. I was impressed most by x, y and z."

Answer (score -1):

If you work with them, write about how good they were in the office, how they did work and how it helped the company.

Comment: Would you explain what you mean by "helped the company"? A kind reminder: this is Academia Stack Exchange.

Comment: How the employee was helping the company increase revenuw, bring more business, team-work, helping co-workers, that kind of stuff!

Comment: The OP said: "The letter is to support the application of a **student** to an award.". Do you assume the student works in a company?

Comment: Indeed, my assumption is that the asker is a faculty member at the student's university and there is no "company" or "office" involved.  I've asked the asker to clarify, but I suspect this answer is not applicable.